# Resolve potential memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, core-foundation, abaddressbook

I am getting the following memeory leaks after running analyze tool in xcode

```
//Getting memeory leak warning here "Potential leak of an object allocated and stored into 'phones'
ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

//Getting potential leak error for line below
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty))!=0)
{
    //Getting potential leak error for line below
    CFStringRef pNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones,0);
    phoneNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)pNumber];
    NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
}
```

How can I resolve these leakages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phones) != 0)
{
    CFStringRef pNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones,0);
    phoneNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)pNumber];
    NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
    CFRelease(pNumber);
}
CFRelease(phones);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `pNumber` is copied, you need to release it: `CFRelease(pNumber)`.

You need to redo your `if` condition so that it uses `phones`, and then release `phones`.

Comment: thanks! But what about the leak on 'if (ABMultiValueGetCount(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty))!=0)'?

Comment: Like I said. There is no need to make a new copy of the values just to count them. Use the one you already have in `phones` — and `CFRelease(phones)` at the end of that code snippet.